# How to set the current time in a DateTimePicker

Tags: c#, winforms, datetimepicker

I am trying to set the current time to a DateTimePicker (with Format Time) like

```
this.myDateTimePicker.Value = DateTime.Now;
```

but when executing my code I am getting an exception

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object
```

What I am doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: `myDateTimePicker` is null. That's all we can infer from the code you posted.

Comment: Hard to tell from the snippet you posted.  Can you expand your example?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to put that code after the `InitializeComponent()` call is made. There is no instance of `myDateTimePicker` until that point.

Answer (score 8):

Declare your `DateTimePicker` and try it.

`DateTimePicker myPicker = new DateTimePicker;`
`myPicker.Value = DateTime.Now;`

Like someone pointed out, put your code before the `InitializeComponent()` since it's in that part that your `DateTimePicker` gets initialized.

1 - Delete you control
2 - Re-add it.
3 - Watch where you put your code.

Should work after that since your doing it right on the code part.

Answer (score 1):

If you use WPF, not WinForms, add this reference:

```
xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
```

Then in XAML DatePicker's code add:

```
SelectedDate="{x:Static sys:DateTime.Now}"
```

Comment: The tag says winforms... so no, OP is not using WPF.

Answer (score 0):

set this code in your 'form1_Load' event

```
DateTimePicker dtpPurDate = new DateTimePicker;
dtpPurDate.Text = DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString();

private void form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     DateTimePicker dtpPurDate = new DateTimePicker;
     dtpPurDate.Text = DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you working with Forms just add DateTimePicker object from Toolbox , and first call InitializeComponent()
Or just create new instance in your code

```
 this.dateTimePicker1 = new System.Windows.Forms.DateTimePicker();
```

Only after creating instance of an DateTimePicker you can use it:

```
this.dateTimePicker1 .Value = DateTime.Now;
```